# How To Send Sequence of Specific Object To Mvc Core Action through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

I was created a function that is responsible to created and sending a json :

```
function Send(op) {
    var tr = $(op).parents('tr');
        var item = [];

        $(tr).find("td").each(function () {
            item.push($(this).find("input").prop("name") + '":' + '"' + $(this).find("input").val());
        });
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(item);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Edit',
            data: myJsonString,
            type:'post',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                alert('send is okay')
            }
        });
}
```

to an IActionResult :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([FromBody]Hazine hazine)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

but it (Edit Action) cant get object from jquery.
so this Action Invoked Succcefully but with null hazine!

a json created which I get from console.log is :

```
["id\":\"4","undefined\":\"undefined","undefined\":\"undefined","HazineType1\":\"1","HazineType2\":\"1","SendDate\":\"5","ProjectId\":\"1","Mablagh\":\"1","MablaghPaid\":\"1","HazineDate\":\"1","HazineDateLong\":\"1","HazineTitle\":\"11111","HazineComment\":\"1","ForoshgahName\":\"1","PayLastDate\":\"1","PayDateLong\":\"111111111","UniqueId\":\"1111","SaveDate\":\"8888","SaveDateLong\":\"888","SendDate\":\"5","SendDateLong\":\"5"]
```

what was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class Hazine:TableBase
{


    [Key]
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }



    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int HazineId { get; set; }


    public int HazineType1 { get; set; } // check paid , check




    public int ProjectId { get; set; }



    public int Mablagh { get; set; }




    public int MablaghPaid { get; set; }




    [StringLength(150)]
    public string HazineDate { get; set; }




    public long HazineDateLong { get; set; }



    [StringLength(150)]
    public string HazineTitle { get; set; }




    [StringLength(350)]
    public string HazineComment { get; set; }



    [StringLength(150)]
    public string ForoshgahName { get; set; }




    [StringLength(150)]
    public string PayLastDate { get; set; }




    [StringLength(150)]
    public long PayDateLong { get; set; }               

}

    public class TableBase
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool isModified { get; set; }



    [StringLength(150)]
    public string SaveDate { get; set; }



    public long SaveDateLong { get; set; }



    [StringLength(150)]
    public string SendDate { get; set; }




    public long SendDateLong { get; set; }

}
```

Console Log:

```
{"HazineId":"4","UniqueId":"1111","HazineType1":"1","HazineType2":"1","SendDate":"5","ProjectId":"1","Mablagh":"1","MablaghPaid":"1","HazineDate":"1","HazineDateLong":"1","HazineTitle":"11111","HazineComment":"1","ForoshgahName":"1","PayLastDate":"1","PayDateLong":"111111111","SaveDate":"8888","SaveDateLong":"888","SendDateLong":"5"}
```

It Work:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit([FromBody]Object data)
    {
       Hazine hazineJson =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hazine>(data.ToString());

        hazine.Update(hazineJson);
        return View();
    }
```

It not work:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit([FromBody]Hazine data)
    {

        hazine.Update(data);
        return View();
    }
```

in second function cant call and err 500 occure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For sending object to Controller with `FromBody`, the json string should map the parameter.

For your action, it accept an object, but for your json, you are sending a collection object.

Try something like below:

```
function Send(op) {
    var tr = $(op).closest('tr');
    var item = {};

    $(tr).find("td").each(function () {
        item[$(this).find("input").prop("name")] = $(this).find("input").val();                    
        });
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(item);
    console.log(myJsonString);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Edit',
            data: myJsonString,
            type:'post',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                alert('send is okay')
            }
        });
}
```

If you are using .net core 3.0, you also need to configure the json serializer by installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and configure it like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

Comment: tnx for good replies . but there is a problem. (I used mvc core 2.2) . it work for Object not Hazine  . I Wonder why

Comment: @AminSoraya What is `Hazine`?

Comment: Hazine Is a Class That i Want to Map Json to it .Actually I send jsons that figure out Hazine

Comment: @AminSoraya Share us the defination for `Hazine`

Comment: Okay .I was Figure Out Hazine Objects Into table .so when user click on one records it called function Send(op) . (this table contain many of Hazine records) and create json  and sending to an action result fo update

Comment: I want To Directly Map Json to Hazine. instead of convert it inside ActionResult. If it not possible I will close the thread

Comment: @AminSoraya What is your current request in the console and what is the code for `Hazine`?

Comment: plz checking new post

Comment: @AminSoraya Can you use `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` in your project? Share us a mini demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: sure checking end of the new post again

Comment: error 500 call when I invoke a second action method bellow

Comment: @AminSoraya Is there any demo to reproduce?

Comment: the only thing I can do is to post an image of error in console and cause an error.plz visit end of the new post again